# Redireccionar de http a https con .htaccess exceptuando algunas páginas o carpetas

Tags: apache, .htaccess

El problema es el siguiente: Tengo el host `http://www.midominio.cl` que a través de una rutina de `.htaccess`, en el public,  es redirigido a `https://www.midominio.cl` Hasta aquí todo bien. El problema surge que, con la rutina que adjunto, me redirige todo incluyendo subdominios y dominios adicionales que no cuentan con el certificado SSL. La idea es: Solo redirigir de **http** a **https**, `midominio.cl` y sus dependencias y no a `consultora.midominio.cl` u otra carpeta donde tenga un dominio adicional. Intenté también incluyendo una rutina PHP en el encabezado del index del subdominio pero obviamente se me produce un bucle de redireccionamiento.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^midominio\.cl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

// hasta aquí funciona la redirección de hhtp a https //

// Las siguientes líneas no funcionan //

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^consultora.midominio\.cl [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Busqué en stackoverflow.com (En ingles) y hay una consulta similar cuya respuesta no funcionó (o no logré entenderla). [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715724/modrewrite-rewritecond-to-turn-off-ssl-redirect-for-a-certain-requested-url ]

Bueno, se agradece la ayuda.

**Actualización.**

Pude evitar la redirección a un subdominio con la siguiente línea

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=subdominio.midominio.cl #Nueva línea
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^midominio\.cl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Pero aun no puedo evitar la redirección a un `otrodominio.cl` que tengo aparcado.

Comment: creo que en el titulo puede haber un error hhtp -> http ? Saludos

Comment: Solucionado. (La dislexia compulsiva... ) Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno hoy he tenido un tiempo para resolver esto y me di cuenta que la solución era más fácil de la que parecía.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=consultora.midominio.cl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.otrodominio.cl 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^midominio\.cl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Caso Cerrado. Dejo la respuesta por si a alguien le sirve.